# Obesity/Inactivity Data at a census tract level

Tags: medical, us-census, census, csv

Looking for obesity/inactivity data for adults at a census tract level for the state of California. Any good sources? Preferably in a format that can be uploaded to arcdesktop.

Comment: https://nccd.cdc.gov/500_Cities/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=DPH_500_Cities.InteractiveMap&islStates=59&islCategories=UNHBEH&islMeasures=OBESITY

Comment: @AnthonyDamico, this comment would be a good answer.